# Disable the delGridRow's confirmation box in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

How to disable the delGridRow's confirmation box ?? because i don't want to inform the changes to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To solve the problem you can just simulate click on the "Delete" button having id="#dData" inside of [afterShowForm](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events2):

```js
afterShowForm: function ($form) {
    $("#dData", $form.parent()).click();
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DeleteWithoutConfirmation.htm).